# Magento 2.1.1 Cart always empty | section-config.js error

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart, mini-cart

In Magento 2 I've updated it to latest version to solve cart issue.

When I click on **Add to Cart** Button it redirect me to cart page(Even in backend "**After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart**" I've set it to **No**) and it always show **Cart is empty** and after click Add to cart button I'm getting following error in my console.

[image]

**In my backend cookie setting is as follow ...**

[image]

Also there is no **session** folder in **var**

How can I solve this issue??

Let me know if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've removed Magento default class `columns` and `product-info-main` in from the div so that's why add to cart didn't work but after adding those class again as it was add to cart has started working properly.